# Submit form using Django views and redirect to React path

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, url

I have a form that on submit goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/all/new/ in order to trigger a view function that creates a new object.

booking.js

`form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/all/new/" method="POST"> ... /form`

After creating the object, I want to go back to the homepage that's rendered by React ("http://localhost:3000/"). How can I do this?

views.py

`@api_view(["POST"]) def create_object(request): ... return Response(serializer.data)`

urls.py

`urlpatterns = [ path("new/", views.create_booking, name="create_booking"), ]`

Comment: It depends on who is in control over navigation on the frontend. Are you using something like React Router?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes I am.

Comment: Then consider using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send the HTTP request with JavaScript. That will enable you to trigger React Router to go to the home page whenever you receive a response from your Django backend.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Using fetch did exactly what I wanted. Thank you!